# How migrate resource group from a disabled subscription to a working directory in Azure

Tags: azure

I am a student studying a masters degree in IT at the University of Aberdeen, Scotland. We were using a Microsoft Azure free trial for our project, however it ran out and locked in all of our work. We are working with a professional client who have their own working directory. We are unable to transfer our resource group from our locked directory to their professional one. Is there any way to remove this lock? or is there a way to contact Microsoft directly and ask them to release our project? It's essential to myself and 4 other group mates, and would be a disaster if we could not migrate the project.

TIA for any help

Comment: You could convert your trial subscription to a paid one, transfer the resource group and then cancel that subscription.

Comment: See, I converted it to a pay-as-you-go one but still it is locked. I may just subscribe for a full one then cancel once the mirgation is done

Comment: It should work. Please open a support ticket in Azure Portal. They should be able to help.

Comment: Billing support requests are free so you don’t really need to purchase a support plan.

Comment: Thank you, I will try

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question for Azure support and not a programming related question.

Comment: Yeah go for it, when looking for help Azure directed me to Stack Overflow...

Comment: I don't blame you...sometimes it's a ping-pong situation :). You get directed here for support and then got sent back to Azure Support. Primarily this site is for programming related questions. Another good way to reach out to Azure Support is on Twitter (@AzureSupport). They are extremely responsive there.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I will try to get this sorted.